# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests in search() of googlesearch package of Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver, google-search

Actually, I am running one query in the search() of GoogleSearch package of python which gives multiple links from the google search in a list format

```
search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=20, start=0, stop=None, pause=2.0):
```

I am able to get the result also but after some time it gives an error like

```
for i in search(query, tld='com', lang='en', num=20, start=0, stop=None, pause=2.0):
  File "E:\crawling\venv\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 312, in search
    html = get_page(url, user_agent)
  File "E:\crawling\venv\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 176, in get_page
    response = urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\shubh\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

I have also increased the pause time in the search parameter but didn't help for me.

Comment: Hey did you fix you're problem ? You're problem is because google ban you're ip

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you were using the official Google Search API but it has been [officially deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/api-shutdown).

However, there's a [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) alternative from a third-party API SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

It will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google and other search engines, and no need to create the parser and maintain it.

It has a pagination to extract data from all a Google Search pages which is used in a `while True` loop in which pagination parameters will be specified with a condition for exiting the loop:

```py
while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:                   
        organic_results_data.append({
            "page_num": page_num,
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "link": result.get("link"),
            "displayed_link": result.get("displayed_link"),   
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
```

Pagination conditions are: if the next page exists, a transition to it occurs and the next request occurs already on this page, and so it will continue until the next page exists. As soon as the next page is missing, the loop will stop:

```py
if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))        # updating search parameters for the next page
    else:
        break
```

Code with pagination and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/stackoverflow-scrape-google-search-with-pagination-serpapi#main.py)

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),  # serpapi key
  "engine": "google",               # serpapi parser engine
  "q": "google",                    # search query
  "num": "100"                      # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)       # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "page_num": page_num,
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "link": result.get("link"),
            "displayed_link": result.get("displayed_link"),   
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "page_num": 1,
    "title": "Google",
    "link": "https://www.google.com/",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.google.com"
  },
  {
    "page_num": 1,
    "title": "Google - About Google, Our Culture & Company News",
    "link": "https://about.google/",
    "displayed_link": "https://about.google"
  },
  {
    "page_num": 1,
    "title": "The Keyword | Google",
    "link": "https://blog.google/",
    "displayed_link": "https://blog.google"
  },
  {
    "page_num": 1,
    "title": "Google - Twitter",
    "link": "https://twitter.com/google",
    "displayed_link": "https://twitter.com › google"
  },
  {
    "page_num": 1,
    "title": "Google - Home | Facebook",
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Google/",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.facebook.com › Google"
  },
  #...
]
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.